# Python CSV to list (1-dimensional list)

Tags: csv, python-3.4

I want to make a system which is dynamically and real-time. When I print the list I get: [['amsterdam', 'new york', 'hongkong', 'berlin']]. What I would like to get is: ['amsterdam', 'new york', 'hongkong', 'berlin']. So instead of two brackets I want just one bracket. How can this be acomplished?

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    return list(readcsv)
csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are printing the value.

Comment: you do not need to close the file as you are using with open(...):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the index

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    flatlist = (list(readcsv))[0]

print flatlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list of lists by this

```
return [x for sublist in readcsv for x in sublist]
```